# Parse Background Job Pending, Not Running

Tags: parse-platform, background-process

I am working on a Parse app and I need it to run a background job once a day that gets data from a site and stores it into the database.  However, the job always gets stuck at "Pending."  It is claimed to be resolved at facebook, but it doesn't work for me.  Here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("myJob", function(request, status) {
    console.log("Working");
    status.message("Working!");
});
```

It correctly shows the job, and I can run it, but it always gets stuck on "Pending."  I waited for three hours, still pending. Used a different app, no luck.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Corresponding Bug Report on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721251361289141/).

Comment: The Jobs seem to abort after about 5 hours. I have the same problem so I deleted my app and started fresh. Still not working even with a trivial test background job, which immediately execute status.success();.

Comment: @Simon agreed.  After five hours it just complains that it failed because status is not called.

Comment: The Parse team seems to be on it, see http://status.parse.com/incidents/w7ck2fg641kn

Comment: It seems to look better now, a few of my jobs ran through. They are probably working through a backlog of jobs. I'm guessing it's going to be fine in a few hours.

Comment: @Simon I hope so.  It's still not working for me.. :-(

Comment: It's working quite well for me now. See the Facebook Bug

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar right now — Cloud jobs should be limited to 15 minutes but one of the jobs has been running for well over that amount of time already. I wonder how long it'll take for that job to die off and let things get back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call **status.success();** or **status.error();** at least once. After that it will update the status.